# Correctness of using of "far from"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Let's say a friend said to his friend that the man which they both saw looks like another one which was next to that one and one of them says that that man looks like him and his friend says that it's not in this manner below.

Then is it grammatically correct to say like this in response?

> He's far from ***being looks like*** him

or

> He's far from ***being similar*** to him

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"being looks like" is incorrect in this case as it is passive, but you need it to be active.

You could also say "He's far from looking like him". When you want to use "far from" with a verb, you must use a present participle.

It would probably be more idiomatic to say something like "His looks are far from his".

Comment: And what about the second one, how to say this rightly?

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but less idiomatic than my and fev's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I would say

> He looks nothing like him.

However, for more idiomatic uses of ***far from being/doing something*** you
can check [this link](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/far-from-something), though it is ***far from being exhaustive*** :)